# Как подключить собственную библиотеку в Xcode?

Tags: c++, функции, xcode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто работает на макосе, как Вы подключаете собственные библиотеки?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, добавьте подробностей, что именно вы хотите подключить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я уже разобрался :)